# Transition on hover not working for a href link

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, transition

I'm trying to get my my button to transition on hover so the button squeezes to the left. However, there is no transition occurring on hover. Any suggestions?

```css
.BtnEvents {
  background-color: #048431;
  /* FRB Green */
  margin: 10px 0px;
  padding: 16px 30px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: all 200ms ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 200ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 200ms ease;
  fit: fill;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: visible;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Sofia Pro', sans-serif;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: static;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 400px;
}

.BtnEvents:hover {
  transition: all 200ms ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 200ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 200ms ease;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank" class="BtnEvents">Register Now!</a>
```

Comment: You are not telling CSS in `:hover` what it should transform to.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now. Thank you for the advice! I changed the hover callout to: .BtnEvents:hover {
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-left: 25px;
}

Comment: Also, CSS transitions are so widely supported now you no longer need to add vendor prefixes anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.BtnEvents {
  background-color: #048431;
  /* FRB Green */
  margin: 10px 0px;
  padding: 16px 30px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: all 200ms ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 200ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 200ms ease;
  fit: fill;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: visible;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Sofia Pro', sans-serif;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 400px;
  transition: all 200ms ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 200ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 200ms ease;
}

.BtnEvents:hover {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank" class="BtnEvents">Register Now!</a>
```

Comment: Thank you! I changed the hover callout and was able to get that to work.

Comment: great was going to say just change the width in my example to what you needed. Please tick if it helped you solve your issue.

Comment: I've ticked your comment, however, since I've got a low reputation score it won't impact the public vote count. Really appreciate your help!